# A star algorithm finding shortest path but not computing it correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

Using the following A star visualization as a way to compare path accuracy, I found a large variation between my implementation and this one.

https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

Path I'm comparing to:

[image: Path I'm comparing to]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/a867d5d942.png))</sub>

My test paths:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/a8cebd8506.png))</sub>

There are times when it seems like the algorithm is checking too few nodes (i.e Test#6). Is this to be expected, or is it not correct?

Important variables in algorithm:

```
TileMap* m_tileMap;
vector<Tile*> m_openList;
vector<Tile*> m_path;

// Direct mapping of 2D tile map. 
// Stores the list type for the same-indexed tile 
vector<vector<int>> m_listMap;
```

Comparator for sorting open list:

```
struct CompareNodes
{
    // sorts lowest F cost to end of vector
    bool operator() (Tile* lhs, Tile* rhs)
    {
        return lhs->getFCost() > rhs->getFCost();
    }
};
```

High level implementation:

```
vector<Tile*> PathGenerator::generatePath(Tile* startNode, Tile* endNode)
{
    setUpListMap();

    startNode->setGCost(0);
    startNode->setHCost(calculateHCost(startNode, endNode)); // Manhattan (no diagonal). { abs(y2 - y1) + abs(x2 - x1) }
    startNode->calculateFCost(); // calculates G+H internally

    m_openList.push_back(startNode);
    Vector2D startNodePos = startNode->getMapPos();
    m_listMap[startNodePos.x][startNodePos.y] = LIST_TYPES::OPEN;

    Tile* currentNode;


    while (m_openList.empty() == false)
    {
        currNode = m_openList[m_openList.size() - 1];
        m_openList.pop_back();

        Vector2D currNodePos = currNode->getMapPos();
        m_listMap[currNodePos.x][currNodePos.y] = LIST_TYPES::CLOSED;

        if (currNode != endNode)
        {
            vector<Tile*> neighbours = findNeighbours(currNode);
            removeUnnecessaryNodes(&neighbours); // remove walls and closed nodes
            computeCosts(&neighbours, currNode, endNode);
            addUniqueNodesToOpenList(&neighbours); // ignores duplicates and then sorts open list
        }
        else
        {
            m_path = getPath(currNode);
            resetLists(); // erases all vectors
        }
    }

    return m_path;
}

void PathGenerator::computeCosts(vector<Tile*>* nodes, Tile* current, Tile* end)
{
    int newGCost = current->getGCost() + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes->size(); i++)
    {
        Tile* node = nodes->at(i);
        unsigned int nodeGCost = node->getGCost(); // G cost defaults to max int limit

        if (newG < nodeGCost)
        {
            // set up node costs like above
            node->setParentNode(current);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the most important code. If the high level functions don't help to find the source of the issue, let me know and I'll add the implementation for them also.

Help appreciated.

Comment: The only difference I can visually appreciate is that you don't move along the diagonal..

Comment: @Boiethios: Added question

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: I set the rules in comparison path to also not use diagonals

Comment: yeah, my fault. So pink = explored, light-blue = pending exploration? or the opposite?

Comment: seems to me this question is more like a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) no?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: You can ignore the pink as that's related to something else in the simulation. Light blue is what has been explored, dark blue is the path

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: What's the function of code review?

Comment: Oh, then it is strange that your algorithm explores such a large area in the picture, when it looks like the blue path would not be the last to be found. Perhaps the termination condition is not right, and you simply go on until you exhaust explorable nodes, instead of stopping asap you hit the destination?

Comment: I am confused when you say that your algorithm results in 'gaps', because I don't see them in your picture.

Comment: @sookie Your code is working but you want a better result, I think you'll have more concerned people on the code review site.

Comment: From What I see/understand from your images, each closed nodes seems correct (`dist(start, node) + heuristic(node, end) < dist(start, end)`).

Comment: @sookie `currNode = m_openList[m_openList.size() - 1];`  This could simply be `currNode = m_openList.back();` .  Second, it is strange you're passing the address of a local vector in the `if (currNode != endNode )` block.  Not knowing what those functions do, it raises red flags.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: An example of the gaps I mentioned can be seen in the last stretch of Test#4. It's the unexplored nodes present within the explored area. These types of 'gaps' are present in the working pathfinder, but are minimal. I'm not sure if this is the expected output or not.

As for termination, it's a simple check to see if the currentNode equates with the endNode. I can produce paths where the there are no other explored nodes other than the path itself, which suggests this isn't the problem.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: The code is finding the shortest path, but I wouldn't say it's doing it correctly. I'm hoping to identify where this incorrectness is being produced

Comment: @Jarod42: The sorting algorithm is fine. At least when I look into the vector's elements, they are sorted correctly. But something else is causing the algorithm to explore nodes that shouldn't have been.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: I'm passing the address of the local vector so that the function may modify it without the need to make a copy. Should I include the implementation of these functions in the question?

Comment: @sookie: I don't talked about sorting algorithm, but I don't identify the nodes which should not be visited in your example (it would be different if start/end are reversed). The different light red to ignore doesn't help either, as the strange symbols.

Comment: @Jarod42: You're right. It seems there are no additional nodes being checked than what's needed. So my final concern - are too few nodes being checked (say in Test#6)? I've updated question to reflect this

Comment: @sookie: Can you point the problematic node(s) ? (From your image, I don't understand which node are not visited BTW).

Answer (score 0):

The sorting part seems correct, but since it's a vector this should be very easy for you to verify.

Instead, try using a for-loop as a test-case to make sure you're really get the lowest f-cost node:

```
Tile* currnode = m_openlist[0]; 
for (int i = 0; i < m_openList.size() i++) 
{ 
    if (m_openList[i]->getFCost() < currnode->getFCost()) 
        currnode = m_openList[i]; 
}
```

See if that fixes it. If it does, there's an issue in your sort, but i'm not sure what the issue would be.

Also, in your computeCosts function, you do:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes->size(); i++)
  {
      Tile* node = nodes->at(i);
      //.. other code
  }
```

Since you're using an std::vector, why not make use of its functionality, and use iterators or a range based loop:

```
// Iterators
for (auto it = nodes->begin(); it != nodes->end(); it++)
{
    Tile* node = *it;
    //.. other code
}

// Range based loop
for (auto node : *nodes)
{
    //.. other code
}
```

Comment: The idea here is to update previously computed nodes if the current path produces a better F cost for that node. At the beginning I initialize all tiles with a G cost of `numeric_limits<int>::max()` so `newG` will always be less than that node's G Cost when that node is first encountered. Any further encounters with that node will utilize that if statement correctly

Comment: I see, my bad! Anyway, the only real place something can go wrong is with the node selection from the open list...An error anywhere else would likely compute a wrong path, or not find it at all. Can you verify that the nodes are sorted when taking the node off the open list? And how sure are you you're rendering everything correctly?

Comment: Here is the end section of Test#4 http://i.imgsafe.org/ab65330c78.png ... The parts in yellow are the gaps I was talking about - they are the unexplored nodes. In working A-star implementations, I have never seen that number of unexplored nodes and I'm wondering if this is a problem or if it's fine. Also, is there a performance benefit to using iterators over index-based loops?

Comment: It is strange, and it really shouldn't happen so there is definitly something not quite right. As I said in my previous answer, it seems to have something to do with taking the node with the lowest F-value of the open list, therefore taking the wrong node off occasionally and stopping the current path. As for the iterator / range based loop: the std::vector::at does bounds checking every time you try to call it. Since you know for sure you'll be within the range of your vector, there's really no need for this. What you can also do is `Tile* node = nodes[i]`.

Comment: Here is a log of FCost values in the openList - http://pastebin.com/kMZy4ud1 ... I only output when currentF != prevF, which will remove duplicates while still showing any problems with sort. You were right that vector is not sorted properly at times (see line 400). But the vector still maintains lowest FCost at top

Comment: The fact it's not sorted at places means it doesn't work and therefore will cause undefined behaviour. As is visible in your images, MOST of the times, it does indeed keep the lowest fcost at the top, but there is no guarantee it will always have it at the top. Try a simple for-loop to get the lowest f-value from the open list as a test-case and see if the pahtfinding works then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130232/discussion-between-sookie-and-xeric-xd).